# Ways to include unsolved problem in research paper

Tags: math-history, research

Currently i am writing a paper in which i have proved a result but i have the extension of the same result which i think should be true but i could not prove it. I want to leave it for readers of my papers.

> what are some good ways to write an unsolved problem in research paper?

Any example of old papers would be helpful.Thanks

Comment: Don't you have someone to guide you?

Comment: I have seen some papers put a "further questions" section at the end of their paper

Comment: @Jakobian: I dont.

Comment: @Max, Thanks but i have only one problem so i dont think that would be appropriate way.

Comment: That's rough. I wish you good luck then.

Comment: @Jakobian: Thanks,i appreciate your concern.

Comment: If you read any research paper which is longer than 5 pages, you're very likely to learn how to do just that.

Answer (score 5):

Learn from the old masters:

"In fact a more general result is true. I have a truly marvelous proof of this more general theorem which this margin is too narrow to contain."

:)

Comment: Ah Ferma, loved this answer!

Comment: Ok...yours is *totally* better than mine. :)

Answer (score 3):

You write something like "Having proved Theorem 3.2, it's natural to ask whether
*every* snorkle is in fact redundant. This is clearly the case in dimensions 1 and 2, and the Riemann hypothesis implies the results in dimensions 7 and higher, as we'll now show, but for dimensions $3$ through $6$, the question remains open, and even in dimensions $7$ and higher, there may be a far simpler proof than the one that would result from any proof of RH. Section 8 addresses these topics briefly, with a few ideas on possible approaches."

Comment: If the problem is clearly stated, or can be proposed clearly, OP may write a conjecture (in a similar style to thms, props etc). It would aid the reader to know exactly what OP is looking for. Your paragraph would then function as an intuition to why the conjecture makes sense.

Comment: Agreed -- that'd be fine.

Comment: Thanks,John. Very helpful.